# Python Loop Crash at if Statement: if c != i & c != a & c != b:

Tags: python

I have got a problem with an if statement in a while loop, it crashes everytime at the same place: if c != i & c != a & c != b:. When I comment out this statement it works. Has anyone a clue why?
Here is the code fragment:

```
while COUNT < GENERATIONS:       
    for i in range(0,NP):
        while True:
            a = randint(0,NP-1)
            if a != i:
                break
        while True:
            b = randint(0,NP-1)
            if b != i & b != a:
                break
        while True:
            c = randint(0,NP-1)
            if c != i & c != a & c != b:
                break
```

Comment: `&` is **bitwise** AND, not the logical, boolean `and` operator.

Comment: And what do you mean *crashes*? Do you get a traceback? If so, include the whole traceback in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator, and as a result you getting a very different expression.

Rather than test for `(c != i) & (c != a) & (c != b)`, thanks to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) you *actually* test the expression `c != (i & c) != (a & c) != b`, where `&` does a *bitwise* operation on the `i` and `c`, and `a` and `c` operands.

You want to use the *logical* `and` operator, which has a lower precedence than comparisons:

```
while True:
    a = randint(0,NP-1)
    if a != i:
        break
while True:
    b = randint(0,NP-1)
    if b != i and b != a:
        break
while True:
    c = randint(0,NP-1)
    if c != i and c != a and c != b:
        break
```

Note that if you wanted to pick 3 unique random numbers you could use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) together with an `xrange()` object (`range()` for Python 3):

```
while COUNT < GENERATIONS:       
    for i in range(NP):
        a, b, c = (i, i, i)
        while i in (a, b, c):
            a, b, c = random.sample(xrange(NP), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the bitwise `&` operator, not the boolean `and` keyword. Change `&` to `and` and your code will actually do boolean comparisons.